# Crystal Reports: highlight minimum and maximum value on a chart

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working to highlight the max and min value on a chart. The highlight option from the chart expert isn't much of a help. [image]

Is there a way to do this on a chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 formulas. One to return only the max value, second to return min value and then another to return all data minus the max and min.

```
    //max_value
    If  ({DETAILS.Qty Budget} = maximum({DETAILS.Qty Budget}))         
    then {DETAILS.Qty Budget} else 0


    //min_value
    If  ({DETAILS.Qty Budget} =  minimum({DETAILS.Qty Budget}))     
    then {DETAILS.Qty Budget} else 0

    //all_data 
    If  ({DETAILS.Qty Budget} = maximum({DETAILS.Qty Budget})) 
    or ({DETAILS.Qty Budget} = minimum({DETAILS.Qty Budget}))
    then 0 else {DETAILS.Qty Budget}
```

1. Go to Chart Expert and under "Report Fields" you should see the 3 formulas.

   Add them to "Shows value(s):" box
2. Go to "Color Highlight" tab and select new. Insert your max and min formulas and specify condition for each ( since we are only selecting max and min with those just choose > 0 .

I got the idea from [SAP Support](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/2091102). 
This works for me on CR 23 for Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I'm sorry, but would you mind elaborating a bit further? How do I apply the formula on a chart to change colors? Also, do you know if it is possible to make the highlighted field on a report to reflect on the chart? The max and min values on the report data are already highlighted, so I'm wondering if there is a way to bring them over to the chart automatically.